# CountDownTimer - A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released

Tags: android

I have a problem with my class CountDownTimer. I wrote myself a clock that counts down the time to me. When the countdown is completed in logcat, I got the following error:

```
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode: java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at java.util.zip.Inflater.(Inflater.java:82)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.GzipSource.(GzipSource.java:62)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.unzip(HttpEngine.java:645)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:811)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:776)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:676)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:660)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.j.a(SourceFile:220)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:263)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:132)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.b.a(SourceFile:43)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.b.a(SourceFile:62)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:120)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:61)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.cron.AuthCronService.a(SourceFile:44)
    11-29 11:29:35.980 1689-1699/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.al.run(SourceFile:135)
```

This is the code of my application:

```
    package com.example.ukasz.carrom;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class singles_carrom extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Button start;
    private static TextView timer;
    MediaPlayer finish;
    Counter time = new Counter(30000, 1000);

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_singles_carrom);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        timer.setText("00:00:30");
        finish = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.gong);


        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                time.start();
            }
        });

    }
    public class Counter extends CountDownTimer {
        public Counter(long miliseconds, long interval) {
            super(miliseconds, interval);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
            timer.setText(hms);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            finish.start();
        }

    }
}
```

Please help